# Validações do DataAnnotation não funcionam em propriedades com atributo NotMapped no EF6

Tags: entity-framework, repository, annotation, dataannotations

Atualizei a versão do Entity Framework da 5 para a 6 no meu projeto, e o Context.SaveChanges do Repositório de dados parou de funcionar apenas em alguns casos.

Constatei que ao usar DataAnnotation nas propriedades do meu modelo que continham o atributo [NotMapped] estavam causando uma exceção no DbEntityValidation.

Comentando essas validações passou a funcionar novamente.

```
using PROJETO.Helper.Generic;
using PROJETO.Helper.Resources;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PROJETO.Entity.Models
{

[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Usuário:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "O usuário deve conter no mínimo quatro caracteres e no máximo vinte!")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Senha:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).+$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordFormat", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [CustomValidation.NotEqual("CurrentPassword", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordCompare", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Roles { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Senha Atual:")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "CurrentPasswordRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string CurrentPassword { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar:")]
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirme a senha!")]
    //[Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordConfirmCompare", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CustomMessages))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Manter Conectado")]
    public virtual bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
}
```

Alguém tem uma solução para este caso?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Geralmente utilizamos um padrão para atendar as necessidades da View.

Ao envés da View ser fortemente tipada diretamente com a model utilizamos as chamadas ViewModel.

http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/

Assim a View seria fortemente tipada para a ViewModel, a action receberia uma instancia da ViewModel como parâmetro e a Controller teria a responsabilidade de converter a ViewModel para a Model e assim segue o processo.

Exemplo View

```
@using System.Threading
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model Teste.App.LoginViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="margin:100px 100px 0px 475px;">
    <fieldset style="width:230px">
        <legend>Login do Usuário</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remember)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remember)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Acessar" class="botao" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAutorizador _autorizador;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Principal");
            }

            return View(new LoginViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            try
            {
               //LoginInfo seria a sua entity de login 
               // O método model.ConvertToEntity() converteria LoginViewModel para LoginInfo 
               LoginInfo entity = model.ConvertToEntity(); 
            ....
```